# View laptop power consumption without running it on battery

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, power, prime95

My laptop has a bad battery (lasts 20 - 30 minutes of normal use) but I need to see the max power consumption.I tried running Prime95 + Furmark on battery with power saving off (which took 50 watts just before it shut down) and it said battery low (below 10%) in a few seconds and the second time I tried it on battery it shut down (not overheating).The laptop can run Prime95 and Furmark on AC power perfectly but I want to see how much it takes.

Is the any software or meter which can do this.Also I am using elementary OS (based on Ubuntu Linux)